# Probability space of a sequence of random variables

Tags: probability-limit-theorems

Let $\{b_n(\omega)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of random variables in the underlying probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$. Let $b\in\mathbb R$.

$b_n\xrightarrow{p}  b\equiv\forall\epsilon>0\;\;\mathbb \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb P(\omega\in\Omega:|b_n(\omega)-b|>\epsilon)=1$

The way I understand this definition is the following: given $\epsilon$, for each $n$, $\mathbb P(\omega\in\Omega:|b_n(\omega)-b|>\epsilon)$ is a sequence of real numbers, say $a_n$, so $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb P(\omega\in\Omega:|b_n(\omega)-b|>\epsilon)=1$ refers to the limit of that sequence of real numbers: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=1$.

What happens if each $b_n(\omega)$ comes from a different probability space? For example:$(\Omega_n,\mathcal F_n,\mathbb P_n)$. Then we would have:

$b_n\xrightarrow{p}  b\equiv\forall\epsilon>0\;\;\mathbb \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb P_n(\omega_n\in\Omega_n:|b_n(\omega_n)-b|>\epsilon)=1$

Is this correct? Is this necessary? Or the first definition embodies this second case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it exactly right. The random variables don't need to be defined on the same space, because $b$ is a constant. OTOH if $b$ were a random variable then you would need all the $b_n$ to be defined on the same space in order for the quantity $b_n(\omega)-b(\omega)$ to make sense.

Comment: The last clarification makes a lot of sense. Thank you!